# overpass not returning some POIs

Tags: overpass-api

I am trying to get all POIs around a specified geom (Lat, Lon) but for some reason some POIs are missing in the response.

For example

```
node
  (around:75,54.071497,9.986973);
out body;
```

is not returning "Klatsch Palais" even tough its shown on the map but other items are listed.

Second example is not returning "POCO-Domäne" neither "Club Orange & Blue".

```
node
   (around:75,54.063060,9.968584);
out body;
```

Am I missing some property?

Comment: Why are you expecting your query to return **ways** when you're only querying for **nodes**?

Comment: Maybe I am getting something wrong, but isn't "Klatsch Palais" a node, too? What's the differents to e.g. "Eis-Café Brazil"

Comment: Nope, it's a way: https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/142588482 - I'd highly recommend to look at the data in some editor like iD or JOSM and get some better idea about the OSM data model. It really helps to create better queries.

Comment: Now I am getting it! Thank you!